# populate a spinner from database

Tags: android, database, spinner

hi
   i tried to populate a spinner from DB....

### my code:

```
  String MY_DATABASE_NAME = "testDB"; 
  String MY_DATABASE_TABLE = "testDBrecords"; 
  TextView resultsView; 
  Spinner spinner; 
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapterForSpinner; 

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  setContentView(R.layout.main); 
  spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
  resultsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); 

  SQLiteDatabase myDB = null; 
  myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, 1, null); 
  myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR, Country VARCHAR, Age INT (3));"); 
  myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " (LastName, FirstName, Country, Age) VALUES ('name1b', 'name1a', 'countrya', 34);"); 
  myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + " (LastName,FirstName, Country, Age) VALUES ('name2b, 'name2a, 'countryb', 27);"); 
  Cursor c = myDB.query(MY_DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null); 
  int firstnameColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow ("FirstName"); 
  int ageColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Age"); 
  adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
          adapterForSpinner.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
          spinner.setAdapter(adapterForSpinner); 
  if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
          do { 
                  adapterForSpinner.add(c.getString(firstnameColumnIndex) + " aged " + c.getShort(ageColumnIndex)); 
          } 
          while (c.moveToNext()); 
          if (myDB != null) { 
          myDB.close(); 
      } 
 } 
else { 
  resultsView.setText("DB EMPTY!!"); 
} 
}
```

No error but while run force close....

logCat Error:

```
03-24 03:09:31.501: INFO/Database(546): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "name2a": syntax error
03-24 03:09:31.501: ERROR/Database(546): Failure 1 (near "name2a": syntax error) on 0x1ec430 when preparing 'INSERT INTO testDBrecords (LastName,FirstName, Country, Age) VALUES ('name2b, 'name2a, 'countryb', 27);'.
03-24 03:09:31.743: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(546): Shutting down VM
03-24 03:09:31.743: WARN/dalvikvm(546): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.acarin.project/com.acarin.project.Rough}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "name2a": syntax error: INSERT INTO testDBrecords (LastName,FirstName, Country, Age) VALUES ('name2b, 'name2a, 'countryb', 27);
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "name2a": syntax error: INSERT INTO testDBrecords (LastName,FirstName, Country, Age) VALUES ('name2b, 'name2a, 'countryb', 27);
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1743)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at com.acarin.project.Rough.onCreate(Rough.java:32)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
03-24 03:09:31.981: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     ... 11 more
03-24 03:09:32.178: WARN/ActivityManager(66):   Force finishing activity com.acarin.project/.Rough
03-24 03:09:32.767: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406c9448 com.acarin.project/.Rough}
03-24 03:09:33.693: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{406c9448 com.acarin.project/.Rough}
03-24 03:09:37.055: DEBUG/dalvikvm(282): GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 55% free 2594K/5703K, external 716K/1038K, paused 15976ms
03-24 03:09:41.994: DEBUG/dalvikvm(299): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6K, 54% free 2536K/5511K, external 716K/1038K, paused 317ms
03-24 03:09:43.742: WARN/ActivityManager(66): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{406c9448 com.acarin.project/.Rough}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please post your logcat errors..

Comment: @Chirag thanks for your reply.... yes i post now... pls check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
>   MY_DATABASE_TABLE + "
>   (LastName,FirstName, Country, Age)
>   VALUES (**'name2b, 'name2a**, 'countryb',
>   27);");

You're missing two quotes! Change it to:

> myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
>   MY_DATABASE_TABLE + "
>   (LastName,FirstName, Country, Age)
>   VALUES (**'name2b', 'name2a'**,
>   'countryb', 27);");

Comment: @Flo thank you so much.... now it's running....  will you tell me in it how to add more items at runtime with the use of edittext...

Comment: Please create a new question for your follow up question. Answering it here in the comment won't be very good, because other won't see it here.

Comment: @Flo one problem.... while run "name1a and name2a" only i want in the spinner... so delete the `int ageColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Age"); `... but the problem is while running time all the "name1a and name2a" are adding in the spinner ...now am having more "name1a and name2a" in my spinner but i need that only one time in my spinner ... what s the problem in my code...

Comment: If I understand you correct, each time you start your app, you got one entry more in you spinner, right? The reason for this is, that you do the insert into the database within you onCreate() method. So each time the activity is created the insert statements will be executed again and you got two more rows in your database. So you have to assure that the insert statement are only execute once.

Comment: Another thing I noticed about your code is how you pass the data from the database to the spinner. Using an ArrayAdapter is very cumbersome as there's a SimpleCursorAdapter available out of the box which you can use to bind a cursor to a spinner oder list. Have a look at this tutorial --> http://m.dcpagesapps.com/developer-resources/android/21-android-tutorial-spinners?start=2 . If you're using a CursorAdpater be aware that your Cursor has to contain a column named "_id" otherwise it won't work. So add new column to you tale which is a unique key and has the name "_id".

Comment: @Flo sorry to repeat this question will you tell me how to "assure the insert statement are only execute once".

Comment: I assume that you want to insert the values only once when the app is started the first time. So you need a place to persist the information that the database was already initialized. For persisting data you can use the database, the file system or [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). I think the Shared Preferences are the option you should use. So when you've inserted the data the first time you put this info into the preferences and before you execute the insert statements, you check the preferences if you have already done it.