# Database update in android

Tags: android, database

In my application i have an database in that i have 2 tables.I have 2 following queries:

1.Is it possible to create database with some default value??
2.I have 1 screen in that i have 5 edit boxes,1 save button.When user press the save button the 5 edit boxes value should be updated (replace the old) in the database?

Please help me.

This is for creating database:

```
private static final String DATABASE_SPIN=
"create table spinner(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+" spin text not null);";
```

This is exesql:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
db.execSQL(DATABASE_SPIN);
}
```

My populate code is:

```
Cursor c=db.getAllTitlesSpin();
           startManagingCursor(c);
           int spinColumnIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("spin"); 

//          String group[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group_array);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s2.setAdapter(adapter1);    

            if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
                do { 
                    adapter1.add(c.getString(spinColumnIndex)); 
                } 
                while (c.moveToNext()); 
                if (db != null) { 
                db.close(); 
            } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can create tables with default values in columns

> Each time a row is inserted into the table by an INSERT statement that
>   does not provide explicit values for all table columns the values
>   stored in the new row are determined by their default values, as
>   follows:
>
> If the default value of the column is a constant NULL, text, blob or
>   signed-number value, then that value is used directly in the new row.
>
> If the default value of a column is an expression in parentheses,
>   then the expression is evaluated once for each row inserted and the
>   results used in the new row.
>
> If the default value of a column is CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE or
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, then the value used in the new row is a text
>   representation of the current UTC date and/or time. For CURRENT_TIME,
>   the format of the value is "HH:MM:SS". For CURRENT_DATE, "YYYY-MM-DD".
>   The format for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS".

- you can create and populate a table with output of a `Select` query ([CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT Statements](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) )
- You can copy the contents of one table and use it to populate another table as long the structure of the tables are same. `INSERT INTO Destination SELECT * FROM Source;`

Comment: just append `DEFAULT 'any_value' ` to the column definition, either in create table or alter table

Comment: yes you were quite clear.
 When the user first enters the home screen, you can create the table using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`or simply copy the the data from your db into a new table using `INSERT INTO Destination SELECT * FROM Source;`. Use the new table to populate your UI.

Comment: When user enters 1st time surely the db is empty..So i have to insert this 5 default values into the table,by using an insert query right..So i can this 5 hardcore value...Thats y asked for that query..I can insert 1 value by     public long insertSpinTitle()
{  
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); 
initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Household");return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLESPIN, null, initialValues);
}.How can i insert other 4 values??????

Comment: how about the simple INSERT statement? do it it in a constructor, or the first thing in on create.

Comment: Whether i have to put 5 insert statements to insert 5 row values??

Comment: Whether this code is correct:public long insertSpinTitle()
{  
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
 if(i==1)
initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Household");
 if(i==2)
initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Travel");
 if(i==3)
initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Education");
 if(i==4)
initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Group4");
 if(i==5)
initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Group5");
}

//initialValues.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLESPIN, null, initialValues);
}

Comment: put the insert statement inside the loop and your job is done

Comment: public long insertSpinTitle() { ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues(); for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) { if(i==1) initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Household"); if(i==2) initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Travel"); if(i==3) initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Education"); if(i==4) initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Group4"); if(i==5) initialValues.put(KEY_SPIN, "Group5"); db.insert(DATABASE_TABLESPIN, null, initialValues);} return 0 }

Comment: find some other way to retrieve the rowid of the rows created. It wont be hard.

Comment: K Vinay wadhwa..One more thing...i populating spinner using array adapter..But it is nothing showing in the spinner..following is my code:                Cursor c=db.getAllTitlesSpin();
        startManagingCursor(c);
      
//         String group[]=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.group_array);
         
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
         adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         s2.setAdapter(adapter1);

Comment: sorry, not very well versed with adapters.

Comment: oh...Thanks...IS any easy way to populate spinner value from database??

Comment: Google : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401971/populate-a-spinner-from-database

Comment: Surely i will accept this answer...Now i am populated from database.in that no problem..I called this insert method in oncreate activity..so every time when come to this screen means it is executing,so each time it is adding the value..see my edited post for code

Comment: introduce a static boolean `initialized`  in your activity.

and do a check before you initiaze 


`if (!initialized) { initialize(); initialized=true }`

Comment: k Vinay Wadhwa..one simple thing  db.update(DATABASE_SPIN, initialValues, whereClause, whereArgs); What should i give in place of whereClause and whereArgs..

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using SQLiteOpenHelper to create the database, use the onCreate method to create the databases, and afterwards, enter the default values you want to store there using another db.execSQL() call
2. You can update the values in sqlitedb just like in any other db - use the _id field to identify the row to update

If you are storing just the 5 values ever, [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) are a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Aswin Kumar..I have created the table..Can u explain in detail how to add default value in db.exesql()..I edited my post..Please see that..

Comment: If by "default value" you mean pre-populate the db, then use this:
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("spin","new value");
db.insert("table_name", null, cv);

If you mean to use a value whenever nothing is specified explicitly, then use:
"create table spinner(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"+" spin text not null default \'default_value\');"
see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955461/setting-a-default-value-to-a-column-in-sqlite)